# Update var with value from while loop

Tags: bash

I have the following script and I want to overwrite the `progress` var with the value from the loop but I'm struggling to get this working. I've read many threads but all of them seem to suggest something like writing to output to a file and then read from that again but I don't want to do that.

```
#!/bin/bash

function Upload {
  find . -type f -name "*.test" -printf "%f\n"| sort -k1 | while read fname; do
  progressBar=$(echo "scale=2 ; $progress + $percentage" | bc)
  echo "bar: $progressBar"
  progress=$progressBar
done
}

progress=0
totalFiles=$(find . -name "*.test" | wc -l)
totalCalc=$(($totalFiles + 1))
percentage=$(echo "scale=2 ; 100 / $totalCalc" | bc)

Upload

echo $progress
```

How can I get the var outside the loop/subshell and overwrite the main var?

Comment: Aside from the solution outlined in my answer, you could also write your program in, say, Perl, Python or Ruby, where you have everything in the same process. Your `progressBar` would then simply be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

As you already correctly point out in your question, you are running the loop body in a child process, so even if you would export the variable, a change can't be seen in the parent process.

Writing to a file is and retrieve it in your "main" program is easy if you do it properly:

In your main program (before calling your function), set up the file like this:

```
export progressBarFile=/tmp/progressBar.$$
```

This ensures that several processes of your script use their own file for it.

In your loop, do a

```
echo $progressBar >$progressBarFile
```

Then, after your function, fetch the value using

```
progressBar=$(<$progressBarFile)
```

In the end, you can erase this file like this:

```
rm $progressBarFile
```

If you are really paranoid of having a temporary file left over, you could use `trap` to catch a premature abort of your script, and erase the file inside the trap function.

Another possibility (without using a file) would be to use an array:

```
files=( $(find . -type f -name "*.test" -printf "%f\n"| sort -k1) )
for fname in "${files[@]}"
do
   ...
done
```

In this case, your loop body is not a child process.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The reason I want to avoid writing to a external file is because in the real script I'm writing the progress to a mysql db so my web page can read the progress from it. I figured if it cannot be done without saving the var outside the script, I might as well pull it from my db. I'm not a programmer and kind of learning while I'm working on this so I prefer not adding another programming language into the mix.

Comment: @sjaak : So maybe you can use my second suggestion (using the array to avoid a child process)?